# Rails 4 Authlogic login/logout via Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, authlogic

I'm working on a Rails 4 application using Authlogic gem for the authentication. I'm trying to get a separate React app that can authenticate against the rails api with Authlogic, but the documentation seems a little lacking. So far I can post to an endpoint that creates a new user_session, but it doesn't seem to actually set the cookies.

Here's the create action that the POST request hits to create the session:

```
def create
  @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

  if @user_session.save
    puts @user_session.inspect
    render json: @user_session
  else 
    render json: 'error happened', status: 401
  end
end
```

Here's the react POST request

```
componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get('http://example.lvh.me:3000/api/v1/employees', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, withCredentials: true, data: null})
  .then(res => this.setState({employees: [res.data]}))
  .catch(err => this.setState({employeeErrors: err.response.data.error}))
}
```

That POST request responds successfully, but it doesn't seem to properly create the cookies or session. The response from the POST logs something like this:

```
{"scope":{}, "attempted_record":{"user"....... }, "remember_me": false, "errors": {}, "login": ..., "password": ..., "invalid_password": false, "record": "user": {......} }
```

I can't find much on using ajax for auth with authlogic except a small example in a wiki that doesn't provide any answers.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've been working on the authlogic readme recently and I agree it could use better examples. Let me know if you'd like to help with that.